# How can I dynamically post my message in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, angularjs

I just want to tell the user either with AngularJS or AJAX or JQuery, or whatever is easiest, that the username and email are already registered.

I already have AngularJS implemented for other checks, just not those that need php.

Here is my php function:

```
public function user_exists() {

$username = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('username'));

$data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('email')),
    'password' => crypt($this->db->escape($this->input->
post('password'))),
'user_id' => md5('I really like pie, '. $username)
            );

$does_user_exist = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE 
    `username` = " . $data['username'] . " || `email` = " . 
$data['email'] . "";

$query = $this->db->query($does_user_exist);

if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you use `$data` array in method? To check exists user or not you need use MVC architecture and something like this code.
For model:

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function is_exists($username, $email)
    {
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->where(array(
            'username' => $username,
             'email' => $email
        ));
        $this->db->limit(1);
        return $this->db->get('users')->row('user_id');
    }
}
```

This code for controller:

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{

   public function is_exists()
   {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if(!$this->user_model->is_exists($username, $email))
        {
             $result = array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'Username and email are free');
        }
        else
        {
            $result = array('status' => 400, 'reason' => 'User already exists');
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
   }
}
```

Ajax query:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'user/is_exists',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {username: username, email: email},
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
        if(data.status == 200){
            alert(data.message);
        }
        else{
            alert(data.reason);
        }
    }
});
```

`username` and `email` js variables you need get from your regisration form.
Also you can use [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) or [Tank Auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) extensions

Comment: And is there any way in specific you would suggest to move on to actually registering the user? Your code is very clean and I would very much like to clean mine up.

Comment: To register action you need write some method in ``User_Model`` and put user details as method parameter. You can see example in https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/models/ion_auth_model.php ``register`` method

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the submit button on the registration form submit it using $.post() in jQuery. The action attribute of the form should map to the appropriate controller/method. The method you call can return a JSON encoded message to display in the browser.

It could look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#registration', 'input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
        var form = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.post(action, form, function(data) {
           alert(data.message); 
        });
    });
});
```

In the above example the ID of the form is #registration. The JS var 'data' is the JSON object returned by your PHP method and 'message' is a property of that object containing a message to display to the user.